# Skipping lines and not leaving them blank w/ ofstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a pretty basic ofstream() question. I have an app that matches data that was inputted by a user in a text document. Can i skip lines with ofstream and not modify text already there? If possible, how? Please forgive me my English isn't too great.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int num;
    int numcopy;
    string clientNames[3000];
    string caseNumbers[3000];
    int userInp = 1;
    string confirm = "2";

    cout << "Do you have a file already started (y/n)?"<<endl;
    cin >> confirm;

    if(confirm == "y")
    {
        goto input;
    }
    if(confirm == "n")
    {
        goto postinput;
    }

    input:

    cout << "What is the number of the query last entered?";
    cin >> userInp;
    num = userInp;
    numcopy = userInp;

    postinput:

    for(int i = 1; i <3000; i++)
    {
        userInp ++;
        repeat:
        cout <<"Enter Client's Name:";
        cin >> clientNames[userInp];
        cout << " " <<endl;
        cout <<"Enter Case Number:";
        cin>> caseNumbers[userInp];

        cout <<"Client Name "<< i << " "<<clientNames[userInp]<<endl;
        cout << "Case Number" << i << " "<<caseNumbers[userInp]<<endl;
        cout <<"Is This Correct?"<<endl;
        confirm == " ";
        cin >> confirm;
        if(confirm == "y")
        {
            cout <<"Confirmed"<<endl;
        }

        if(confirm == "n")
        {
            goto repeat;
        }

        if(confirm == "/end")
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    ofstream file;
    file.open("caseData.txt");
    for(int w = 0; w <3000;w++)
    {
        num++;
        file <<
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried, along with desired results and the ones you got?

Comment: here i'll edit it to show so far

Comment: i got stuck at what to do at file <<

Comment: Just so you know, `goto` isn't a very liked feature in all but a specific few cases. Your `input` and `postinput` could be functions, and the `repeat` could be a `while` loop.

Comment: ok, i am new at c++ too, so any suggestions, are helpful

Answer (score 0):

"skip lines with ofstream and not modify text already there" is not possible.

But you can store all lines of the file in your program first. And while you are processing the file, output the stored line when you want to leave that line unchanged.

This effectively does what you want.

Also, you really should get rid of the `goto`s in your code. They should be used only in rare cases. And for beginners, I always feel they should not use it until they are very familiar with programming.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a guess that you want to do something about the circumstance when the user has inputted the same `clientName` or same `caseNumber` multiple times. It is actually not entirely clear from your question that this is what you want to do, but you asked:

> I have an app that matches data that was inputted by a user in a text document. Can i skip lines with ofstream and not modify text already there? If possible, how?

However, I did not see any matching logic in your program. You are simply recording up to 2999 entries (since you don't use the `0` entry of your arrays), or wait until the user enters `/end` as a confirmation message.

If you had actual matching logic, you could detect on input whether the user has typed in the same `clientName` or same `caseNumber`, and you can prompt the user for what to do about it (for example, keep the old existing entry, keep newly entered entry). If you had such logic, you would know that you would only be outputting unique lines of data, and so your output loop would be fairly simple.

There were some comments made on your use of `goto`. Instead of the `repeat:` label, you could start another loop:

```
//repeat:
do {
    // ...read in input, echo it back, wait for confirmation...
    cin >> confirm;
    if (confirm == "y") {
        cout << "Confirmed" << endl;
        break;
    }
} while (confirm != "/end");
if (confirm == "/end") {
    break;
}
```

In this code, anything other than a `y` or `/end` is treated the same as `n`.